# What type of distribution does e^X has?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Given $X_i$ i.i.d random variables that have Geometric distribution with parameter $P_X$

1. How can I formally prove that since $X_i$ and $X_j$ are not dependent, then $e^{X_i}$ and $e^{X_j}$ are not dependent too?
2. How to calculate $E[e^{tX_i}]$ for constant $t$?
   The main problem is that I don't know what type of distribution $e^{X_i}$ has.

Comment: *Hints.* 1. Use the characterisation “$X$ and $Y$ independent $\iff$ $E[f(X)g(Y)]=E[f(X)]E[g(Y)]$ for any bounded measurable $f,g$”.$\enspace$ 2. Use [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician).

Comment: 2- you want to calculate moment generating function of $X$, you can find it e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function in the "geometric distribution" row. How to calculate it you can easily google it with tons of step by step solutions

Answer (score 0):

Hint on 1):

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Then: $$P(f(X_i)\in A,g(X_j)\in B)=P(X_i\in f^{-1}(A),X_j\in g^{-1}(B))$$
Now use that $X_i$ and $X_j$ are independent.